# How to draw circles OVER an image background of a HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I'm drawing a world map to a canvas. I want this world map to plot the coordinates of things dynamically by drawing circles with the arc method. I draw the world map to the canvas, get a URL for the canvas, and there are no errors in drawing the circles... The only problem is the circles are being drawn underneath the image background. Here is my code.

```
// The containing function is a method of an object.
createCanvas: function(done) {
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = _.bind(function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        w = imageObj.width,
        h = imageObj.height;

    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, w, h);

    for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfCoords.length; i++){
       var mapPoint = arrayOfCoords[i];
       //Invoke a function that gets an object {long: x, lat: y}
       var coordinates = returnCoordinatesObject(mapPoint.long, mapPoint.lat) 
       context.beginPath();
       context.arc(coordinates, long, coordinates.lat, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
       context.closePath();
       context.fill();
    }
    var canvasImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    console.log(canvasImage);
    done.call(this, canvasImage);
  }, this);
  imageObj.src="img/le-world-map.png";
},
```

The code isn't erroring so I presume the circles are being drawn, but drawn behind the map. There are other threads on stackoverflow that have asked similar questions but I found them unclear and was unable to implement the solutions suggested...

Thx
--Gaweyne

Comment: How do you know it's being drawn at all? you haven't defined a fill style, could be transparent (though it should be black by default). Have you tried commenting out the code that copies the map, see what happens on a blank canvas?

Comment: Woo. You were right. I had context.fillStyle="red"  but I removed it for some reason. Just put it back. Now for some reason it's not looping through all of the array and only plotting one coordinate circle.

But thank you.